# How to change state in vuex if my variable is an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I just started learning Vue and couldn't find an answer myself.

I have several arrays with data that will be loaded dynamically from the database. The objects inside them have an isLoaded property to identify the loading state.

The question is.

**How can I change the value of isLoaded without passing the entire object to the mutation?**

Like passing only the index and the name of an array.

Right now I do it like this:

```js
    export default new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        books: [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Random',
            img: '',
            href: '/',
            isLoaded: false
          }
        ],
        games: [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Random',
            img: '',
            href: '/',
            isLoaded: false
          }
        ]
      },
      getters: {
        books(state) {
          return state.books
        },
        games(state) {
          return state.games
        }
      },
      mutations: {
        updateLoadStatus(state, item) {
          item.isLoaded = true
        }
      }
    })
```

The isLoaded prop is needed in order to add the preloader class.

```html
<div :class="{loading: !book.isLoaded}">
  <img :src="book.img" :alt="book.title" @load="updateLoadStatus(book)">
</div>
```

I have a lot more arrays than two, so I don't want do a separate mutation for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you define the mutation for it

```
mutations: {
        updateLoadStatus(state, payload) {
          state[payload.key][payload.index].isLoaded = payload.value;
        }
   }
```

and this is how you call it

```
this.$store.commit('updateLoadStatus', { key: 'books', index: 1, value:true}); // based on the object you pass as payload..the mutation will update the corresponding array item.
```